# Discord.py — Check if the user has specific roles?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a command that can ban people on the Server and those who are not on the server. But there is a problem: If I use `async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):` to use the "roles" attribute, then it will not be able to ban those who are not on the server. If i use `async def ban(ctx, member: discord.User, *, reason):` i will not be able to use the "roles" attribute because it is not an attribute.

Why am I doing this? I am trying to make it so that Server Moderators cannot ban those who have Moderator roles

Code:

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.User = None, *, reason=None):
    if get(ctx.author.roles, id=866038959980544050) or get(ctx.author.roles, id=866436325503008768) or get(
            ctx.author.roles, id=866441730631008316) or ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:  # Check if the author has the Role "Moderator", "Admin", etc.

        if get(member.roles, id=867371024466968596) or get(member.roles, id=867132420489871411) and not ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:  # Check if the member has the Role "Moderator", "Admin", etc.
            await ctx.send("You cannot ban this user.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html), you could use a [typing.Union](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-union) converter to ensure that the argument is either a user or a member.

```py
import typing

[...]

async def ban(ctx, user: typing.Union[discord.Member, discord.User]):
```

Note that order matters: By having `discord.Member` first, it tries to apply this [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters) first before trying `discord.User`, thus prioritising conversion to a member over conversion to a user (which should be what you want).

To distinguish between the two cases, you can now check whether `user` is of type `discord.Member` and perform your checks on it.

```py
    if type(user) is discord.Member:
        if YOUR_CHECKS:
            await ctx.send('You cannot ban this user')
            return

    # Perform ban
    await ctx.send('Ban successful')
```

When testing, I discovered that the command library will give you a numerical user id instead of a real user and shows
`Failed fetching discord object! Passing ID instead.` as a warning. If you need more than just the user id, you could convert it to a User object using

```py
    if type(user) is int:
        user = await bot.fetch_user(user)
        if user is None:
            await ctx.send('User not found')
            return
```

Note that `fetch_user` is an API call and you might want to avoid it. See the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to check if the given `member` is in the current guild. If this is `True`, you can create a new `member object` with their id or with another prefered method, otherwise you can assume that they do not have the Moderator role. For simplicity, I only included checking for a **single role**, but you can tweak this in the way you want to do it. Other than that, everything else is explained in further detail in the code below.

```py
if member in ctx.guild.members: # checks if the provided member is in the current server
    member = ctx.guild.get_member(member.id) # Get the member object of the user
    if get(member.roles, id=866038959980544050): # Check if this role is in the member's roles
        await ctx.send("This member has <@&866038959980544050>")
    else:
        await ctx.send("This member does not have <@&866038959980544050>")
    return # returns, since member was in the server
# This happens if the provided member is not in the current server
await ctx.send("This member, who is not in this server, does not have <@&866038959980544050>")
```

[image: Code above working as written]

Answer (score 0):

You must use this

```py
@bot.command(...)
@commands.has_any_role(role id)
...
```